# Is it possible to animate a UIButton to fade or slide off the screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have been browsing SO and various other sites to find out whether this is possible, it definitely seems to be!

The problem I have is every "tutorial" seems to state that the UIButton needs to be inside a UIView of some kind and I can't quite figure out how to get the XIB together to allow the animation.

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just place a button in another view, the animate it's position.
see examples in here: http://github.com/neror/ftutils